# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9091: connect: connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I am using gRPC application and building a simple app. Below the files.

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package com.grpc;

message HelloRequest {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastname = 2;
}
message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}
service HelloService {
    rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

It generates the file normally

```
User.java -> generated from protoc compiler
userGrpc.java -> generated from protoc compiler
```

GRPCService.java

```
package GRPCService;

import java.io.IOException;

import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerBuilder;
import user.UserService;

public class GPRCService {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(9091).addService(new UserService()).build();  
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started at " +  server.getPort());
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

The system.out.println showing the server is running;

```
Server started at 9091
```

And then I opened the firewall rule for TCP on port 9091 on ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 9091 proto tcp
```

Results:

```
java      28277    ubuntu   49u  IPv6   478307      0t0  TCP *:9091 (LISTEN)
```

I can even curl from the terminal

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:9091/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9091 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9091
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 40)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

Curl command

```
   curl -v http://localhost:9091
```

But when executinng from the gui client

[https://github.com/gusaul/grpcox](http://GUI%20Client%20from%20Github)

I get a connection refused.

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9091: connect: connection refused
```

[image: Error from client]

I am not using any VPN nor proxy and the GUI app is actually running inside a container.

```
docker run -p 6969:6969 -v {ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_LOG}/log:/log -d gusaul/grpcox
```

If somebody could please help me.

Thank you Stack !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're running `grpcox` as a docker container, you'll need to give the container either host network access (easiest) so that it can access the server running on the host's (!) port `9901` i.e. `localhost:9901`, or provide it with a DNS address that it can resolve the address your host, i.e. `your-host:9901`.

For host network access, run the container...

```sh
docker run --net=host ... gusaul/grpcox
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing this issue on my Kali `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused` I noticed that my VPN extension is connected on Firefox so I turned it off and everything was normal.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable any VPN that you might be using as it was the case for me.

Comment: What if I'm using it in VM instance? Do I have to configure something or create any firewall policy?